# Whats is the most common way to convert a Timestamp to an int

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp, datetimeindex

I tried multiple ways but they always give me an error. The most common error I get is :

`AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Here is the line where I try to convert my element :

`df.index.map(lambda x: x - oneSec if (pandas.to_datetime(x).astype(int) / 10**9) % 1 else x)`

I tried `x.astype(int)` or `x.to_datetime().astype(int)`

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: I don't use any data here, only a datetime index. If you're talking about the datetime index here's an example : `2019-01-10 15:00:00`

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? basically you should be able to use `df.index.values.astype(np.int64)` which gives you nanoseconds since the epoch. you can work your way on from there.

Comment: I'm trying to remove one second in the indexes that have one second too much. So not all the indexes

Comment: what do you mean by "one second too much"? could you please add a [mre] with exemplary input and desired output? that would make it much easier for people to come up with a good answer (and you'll get it quicker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is necessary use [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=(['2019-01-10 15:00:00','2019-01-10 15:00:01']))

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

mask = df.index.second == 1
print (mask)
[False  True]

df.index = df.index.where(~mask, df.index - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='s'))
    
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2019-01-10 15:00:00, 2019-01-10 15:00:00]
```

Comment: I got `TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''` for this line `df.index = df.index.where(~mask, df.index - oneSec)`
I remove the `% 1` and it gave me the same error